# Zero resistance inductor

Tags: electronics, inductor

I have RF schematic and there is one inductor with no inductance value, but with this.
[image]

Where and how I can buy this inductance? I searched an can't find inductance with 0ohm and 1%. What 1 % does mean?

Answer (score 5):

Without any further information, I would guess that that is a "zero ohm" jumper installed *in place of* the inductor L2.

This often happens on an RF output circuit - the PCB designer isn't sure how much filtering will be required to pass its EMC test. When the prototype is tested, it is found that not all the stages of filtering are required. Then the boards are assembled with no components on the parallel capacitors, and short circuits in place of the inductors. This is less expensive and perhaps saves on some losses in the circuit.
Another possibility is that the board is designed for several different bands, or different applications; the one you have doesn't need the series L in the filter.

The 1% is redundant. But 0 ohm jumpers are sold as resistors, so I suppose they would say 0 ohms 1% just to fit in with the rest of the resistors on the BOM.

Here's an ESP8266 board I have to hand, that has an unpopulated filter section on the RF track (red). The parallel capacitors are missing and a jumper of some sort is in the inductor position. It could be labelled L2 but specified as 0 ohm, like your example.
[image: PCB filter pads]
And another 0 ohm to allow you to change from internal to external antenna (a larger package so you can hand-solder it).

---

You can buy 0 ohm SMD jumpers in any size at a regular electronics supplier, cut tape or reels. Or if it's a once-off, just use a scrap of wire.

Comment: So.. I can use 0 ohm resistor and that's all?

Comment: @Alatriste or any random little bit of wire, or a big blob of solder